# Entity Framework - Issue returning Relationship Entity

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Ok, I must be working too hard because I can't get my head around what it takes to use the Entity Framework correctly.

Here is what I am trying to do:

I have two tables:  HeaderTable and DetailTable.  The DetailTable will have 1 to Many records for each row in HeaderTable.  In my EDM I set up a Relationship between these two tables to reflect this.

Since there is now a relationship setup between these tables, I thought that by quering all the records in HeaderTable, I would be able to access the DetailTable collection created by the EDM (I can see the property when quering, but it's null).

Here is my query (this is a Silverlight app, so I am using the DomainContext on the client):

```
 // myContext is instatiated with class scope
  EntityQuery<Project> query = _myContext.GetHeadersQuery();


  _myContext.Load<Project>(query);
```

Since these calls are asynchronous, I check the values after the callback has completed.  When checking the value of _myContext.HeaderTable I have all the rows expected.  However, the DetailsTable property within _myContext.HeaderTable is empty.

```
foreach (var h in _myContext.HeaderTable)  // Has records
    {
      foreach (var d in h.DetailTable)  // No records
      {
        string test = d.Description;
      }
```

I'm assuming my query to return all HeaderTable objects needs to be modified to somehow return all the HeaderDetail collectoins for each HeaderTable row.  I just don't understand how this non-logical modeling stuff works yet.

What am I doing wrong?  Any help is greatly appriciated.  If you need more information, just let me know.  I will be happy to provide anything you need.

Thanks,

-Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're probably missing is the `Include()`, which I think is out of scope of the code you provided.

Check out this cool video; it explained everything about EDM and Linq-to-Entities to me:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff628210.aspx

In case you can't view video now, check out this piece of code I have based on those videos (sorry it's not in Silverlight, but it's the same basic idea, I hope).

The retrieval:

```
public List<Story> GetAllStories()
{
    return context.Stories.Include("User").Include("StoryComments").Where(s => s.HostID == CurrentHost.ID).ToList();
}
```

Loading the the data:

```
private void LoadAllStories()
{
    lvwStories.DataSource = TEContext.GetAllStories();
    lvwStories.DataBind();
}
```

Using the data:

```
protected void lvwStories_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        Story story = e.Item.DataItem as Story;

        //  blah blah blah....

        hlStory.Text = story.Title;
        hlStory.NavigateUrl = "StoryView.aspx?id=" + story.ID;
        lblStoryCommentCount.Text = "(" + story.StoryComments.Count.ToString() + " comment" + (story.StoryComments.Count > 1 ? "s" : "") + ")";
        lblStoryBody.Text = story.Body;
        lblStoryUser.Text = story.User.Username;
        lblStoryDTS.Text = story.AddedDTS.ToShortTimeString();
    }            
}
```

Comment: I'm testing this now.  My first issue was that I was tyring to do this from the DataContext on the client instead of of the DataService from the server.  I let you know what I find in a few minutes.  Thanks!

Comment: Nope, still having issues.  As soon as I add the .Include("DetailsTabel") I get errors saying some of the fields don't exist.  The fields listed are the ones the EDM created and added to the model - of couse they don't exist on the database.  Clearly I have a lot of studying to do since I am not understanding this.  Thanks for the video - it was hlepful.

Comment: Well, you should have created your model based on your database structure; in fact, two tutorials preceding this one is another that shows you just how to do that with a simple wizard.  I would avoid creating a model myself that mirrors the database structure; just have the IDE generate the model for you, that way all the fields match.

Comment: Yes, I had the tool generate the model from the DB, but since the DB does not use FKs, I added them to the model as Releationships from the tool.  I think the errors I am getting now are because I did not specify a where clause on my Include() - this is making it try to link all fields in both databases.  I'll see if I can find the other tutorials you mentioned.  I looked, but I thought all the other ones were paid tuts?  Thanks...

Comment: I think I found the problem.  My relationships were all screwed up.  I assumed when the model was generated that it would pick my keys to join the tables.  Sometime it did and sometimes it didn't.  The video you linked was what clued me in.  I am going to continue the videos before trying to fix this.  I"ll report back what I find.  Thanks again.

Comment: Oh so you're adding the keys and relationships yourself. I get it now. It does sound like it could be a real-life situation where you don't really wanna make changes to a live database at work, but still want to utilize the key/relationship technique of EDM. That's going to be challenging! Good luck =)

Comment: Well, your post helped me get things working on the server.  Thanks.  I think my current problems are due to the fact that I am using RIA services. Trying to proxy the request is causing issues.  I"ll post another question about that.